# PySide2: QWidget does not work as expected in decorator

Tags: python-3.x, pyside2

here is my code, after executing this code, the window flashed. and then closed

```
import sys

from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget  # required pyside2 == 5.11.2


def run_app(function):

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        function(*args, **kwargs)
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    return wrapper


@run_app
def show_widget():
    """not work as expected

    :return:
    """
    widget = QWidget()
    widget.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    show_widget()
```

What should i do to make the decorator work properly?

Comment: *technically*, you could work around this by using a global variable (possibly, a data structure like a list, and add the new instance to it), as the problem is that `widget` gets out of scope as soon as `show_widget` returns (simply, it gets deleted), but: 1. globals are usually discouraged; 2. creating multiple QApplication instances is also discouraged, and generally causes unexpected behavior and crashes. The actual question is, why do you want to do this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @musicamante I have some windows to test, but I don’t want to create an app instance every time, so I thought of using decorators

Comment: the fact is that you *are* creating an instance everytime with that decorator.

Comment: @musicamante yes, i ignored it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that widget is a local variable that is destroyed as soon as the function is finished executing. A possible solution is for the function to return the widget and be stored in a variable to extend its scope.

```py
def run_app(function):

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        obj = function(*args, **kwargs)
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    return wrapper


@run_app
def show_widget():
    widget = QWidget()
    widget.show()

    return widget
```